# How can I set Google_application_credentials in ec2 instance?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-vision

I just installed google-cloud-vision in my ec2-instance.
To run my code, I just noticed that I sould set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.  (error told me to set it. DefaultcredntialsError)

But I don't know how to get a json credentials and set it within my ec2.
There's a JSON key in my real computer, but how can I move it to my virtual computer?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the service account JSON key file to the EC2 instance using SSH file copy. Set the environment variable to the full path to the file. Make sure you understand the security risks with service account keys.

For advanced users, use [Workload Identity Federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation) to use federate AWS credentials to Google Cloud credentials so that a service account JSON key is not required.